# Stuck with neo4j with python

Tags: python, neo4j

Hi I will try to keep on track but I've done a lot of research and now I just lost. I could really use some expertise here. Below is the situation:

### Preface

This is a follow up question from [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49541009/3766231). The issue there was that my `cypher` queries were taking `1 second` at the minimum to return a response. Even queries like `RETURN 123` also took `1 second`. Which lead to the conclusion [Neo4j Bolt Driver for Python](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/) is slower than an actual `http` call to `neo4j`.

I can back this up with research from [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/1381) and this [from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130370/neo4j-slow-i-must-be-doing-something-wrong-please-tell-me-what-it-is)

### The problem statement

Each time my code runs, it generates upto 10 `Cypher` queries and all those have to be fired and then operations need to be performed based on the results.

> The issue is using `Bolt` the queries take `1 second` to execute and with `HTTP` I am stuck. Since I want to use `Query Parameters` to make the query faster since now it's not `Bolt` as each `http` call now takes `30ms`, multiply that by 10 {since I have 10 queries} and you have a very poor performing python API to fetch user relations. '

### Where am I stuck

1. A confirmation that yes, the `Bolt` driver is slow and that I am not doing anything wrong. Since all the posts I've seen are dated a year back
2. My query has `OR` and `AND` conditions, how can I write those using [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4-preview/cypher/syntax/parameters/) in `neo4j` `REST` Calls.
3. Is there some other `graph` database I should look towards?
4. Is there any way I can fire up to 10 queries and get a response time below `200ms`?

### Other reasons to think I am missing something:

1. The legend has it, `neo4j` is the most popular `graph database`. How is it possible with such drivers?
2. Over 1 year of reported issues with `BOLT drivers` and they still haven't fixed these issues.

## Sample Request

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6Y29kZQ==' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "query" : "MATCH (ct:city)-[:CHILD_OF]->(st:state) WHERE (st.name_wr = {st}) AND (ct.name_wr= {ct}) RETURN st, ct",
  "params": 
  {
    "st" : "california",
    "ct" : "san francisco"
  }
}'
```

but what if I want to add a clause that either `st` should be `California` OR it can be `Alaska` AND `ct` must be `san francisco`, how do I do that with the parameters in `REST`

**EDIT:**

I replicated the script and below is the verdict:

> 58 transactions, tps 0.97 maxdelay 1.08

The `curl` sample request is the one that fire from postman. The code that I am using can be found from the linked question (in the preface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Well to be honest the issue was with the `IP` I was using `localhost` and resolving the `localhost` was taking time. As soon as I switched to `127.0.0.1` it started working perfectly fine.

Marking this as the answer as this answer helped to actually benchmark the two approaches that lead to the discovery of the issue in `host resolution`

---

I think there must be something wrong with your setup. I've been using the 
python bolt driver for a while now, and for simple queries, I don't think I've ever seen a 1 second delay. I don't know what you code looks like, or your network delay, but I wrote a quick example to look at the delays I see in my local network (which has very low latency). Using Neo4j 3.2.9 and python driver 1.5.3.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import time
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

ip = '10.10.10.10'
runtime = 60.0

querystr = 'RETURN 123'
runstart = time.time()
maxdelay = 0
cnt = 0
#driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt+routing://%s:7687" % ip,
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://%s:7687" % ip,
                              auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "password"))
while time.time() - runstart < runtime:
    start = time.time()
    session = driver.session(access_mode='READ')
    ret = session.run(querystr)
    session.close()
    result = ret.data()
    cnt += 1
    delay = time.time() - start
    if delay > maxdelay:
        maxdelay = delay
    if delay > 0.1:
        print('Large delay seen cnt %s delay %0.2f' % (cnt, delay))
print('%d transactions, tps %0.2f maxdelay %0.2f' % (cnt, cnt/runtime, maxdelay))
```

I get the output:

> 117360 transactions, tps 1956.00 maxdelay 0.06

This means the average read took about half a millisecond, and the max was 60ms.

I would look at network latency and issues with resources on both your client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample request is using the *deprecated* [legacy endpoint](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-cypher) and its legacy API.

You should instead use the [transaction endpoint](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api) and its newer API, especially since it supports executing [multiple Cypher statements in a single request](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/query/#_execute_multiple_queries). Each statement can have its own set of parameters.

Comment: But what about the `OR` clause? While matching the name. Also, the new transaction endpoint doesn't mention a way to fire up a `MATCH` query they are all CREATE and COMMIT. can you please post a sample?

Comment: Each statement can be any legal Cypher statement. So, a single request can execute all 10 of your original Cypher statements.

Comment: Regarding the query itself, if your parameter `st` is a list of states, then you can do this: `MATCH (ct:city)-[:CHILD_OF]->(st:state) WHERE (st.name_wr in {st}) AND (ct.name_wr= {ct}) RETURN st, ct

Comment: @InverseFalcon oh yeah I remember that from the docs. Thanks for pointing it out. I just need one last help. Can someone show a sample query with the new transaction endpoint for a MATCH query not a CREATE. Or if I am using the same for both do I have to do a commit for a match as well?

Comment: Links are broken in your answer.